# StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ Inbox isn't notifying

Tags: bug, global-inbox

I am not getting notified about new comments at all.

The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ icon never turns red, and comments in the inbox tab are never highlighted.

If I manually go to the inbox tab, there are lots of comments that I was never notified about.

This has been happening for a week or two now, in Chrome and Firefox on multiple computers.

Comment: I've seen this too, albeit intermittently. Do the live-refresh features work for you (notification of new answers, comments, questions)?

Comment: I had it for a weekend a week or so ago. Seems to have fixed itself for me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes; those work fine.  Fresh page loads still fail to show an inbox.

Comment: @SLaks: Interesting. All the live-refresh features work fine for me too, just *sometimes* the inbox fails to notify me of messages. I can still click on the icon, go to the inbox and *see* the messages though when that happens.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: When that happens, do you see new messages highlighted?

Comment: @SLaks: I do not see new messages highlighted, I realize from other clues that there could be a new message and I visit the global inbox in the drop-box.

Comment: @SLaks I'm glad to hear that you've not been picking up comment notifications, if you know what I mean!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes; I do know what you mean. :)  Interestingly, your comment (this one) was the first comment notification I've seen in ~2 weeks

Comment: I've also missed some notifications today, but it's been intermittent.

Comment: I've seen this again yesterday. Deleted comments seem to be playing a part in this, but I am not that certain yet.

Comment: As for the 'too localized' close vote, several users have now seen this. Yes, it's vague, but it is *not* resolved, nor is it someone's browser. Too Localized is a little premature.